# How to apply color select fixed option

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a dropdown using select. In order to make the the option fixed position, I am using `display:none` for the `first option`. But I want add color to that fixed option, For other options colors are getting applied but not for the fixed option

Here is the code

```css
.fixed-pos{
  display: none;
  color: red; /*this does not apply */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group search-options">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option class="fixed-pos">Search by ..</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>two</option>
  </select>                 
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you fix just the first option in the select menu and not the entire select drop down menu? Your question tags bootstrap but as far as I know bootstrap uses <ul> <li> for there drop down menus. Perhaps thats were the confusion resides?

Comment: I still don't understand why do you need the `color:red` if you do `display:none`

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's not the first option you see. It's the actual select box. This is how you could do it:

```css
select.form-control {
  color: #f00;
}
.fixed-pos {
  display: none;
}
select option {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group search-options">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option class="fixed-pos">Search by ..</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you :-)

PS. You will need to add a class when an option is selected (JavaScript), if you don't want the select box to be red anymore, after selection.